# Lower bounded wildcard method

Tags: java, generics, collections

Could anyone please let me understand why this piece of code is getting compiler error:

```
List<? super A> superList = new ArrayList<>();
superList.add(new Object());
```

While this one is perfectly correct:

```
setSuper(new ArrayList<Object>());

public void superMethod(List<? super A> list) {
    //...
}
```

I understand that lower bound narrows available types to A or their descendants, but why this is fine for compiler when it comes to methods arguments?

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList<Object>` is a valid value of type `List<? super A>`.

An `ArrayList<A>` is *also* a valid value of type `List<? super A>`.

But you can't add `new Object()` to an `ArrayList<A>`.  So not all `List<? super A>` values can add an object, so the compiler correctly errors.